# How does openCVs ORB achieve scale invariance?

Tags: c++, opencv, feature-extraction, feature-detection, orb

After scrolling through the openCVs ORB implementation 
 https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/features2d/src/orb.cpp
and reading the original paper: ORB achieves scale invariance by a scale pyramid, to quote the paper: " We employ a scale pyramid of the image, and produce FAST features (filtered by Harris) at each level in the pyramid"

What I do not understand is how all the features described at each level in the image pyramid combine to give back only  the features in the original image (not subsampled image i.e. 0th level pyramid) that it finds to be the invariant features? So far as I understand the code finds at each level in the pyramid features and give them a description but I do not see/understand if any collapse of the pyramid to the original image even happens, which to me looks as if it needs to be there for comparison of invariant features between images.

Comment: If you go through the code you have posted in your question, you'll see exactly how the descriptor's responses are **weighted** w.r.t. the scale.

Comment: Also, quote from the paper: "One of the issues that we have not adequately addressed
here is scale invariance. Although we use a pyramid scheme
for scale, we have not explored per keypoint scale from
depth cues, tuning the number of octaves, etc.."

Comment: Thank you Rick M. for your reaction! Can you maybe tell me which lines in the code the weighting w.r.t to the scale is achieved? My C++ knowledge is rusty/almost non-existent these days that I can not find it in the code.

Comment: I can see it on line 143 in harrisResponse function